# Asp.Net MVC Core, return view from request.referrer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I created a validateModelErrorActionFilter to automatic validate model before execute my business code, which the filter code is :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class ViewModelValidationActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.ModelState.IsValid) return;
        var controller = (Controller)context.Controller;
        context.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewData = controller.ViewData,
            TempData = controller.TempData
        };
    }
}
```

Some how, I've to handle post request from other action, which can be :
From form in url `site/area/controller/Edit` post to `site/area/controller`.
and when the data is not valid, mvc try to find View from my post handle action `Create`, and I don't have that view, so I get a 404.
My question is, how could I return the view from request.referrer header in actionfilter?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in MVC Core 2 and i solved it in this way:

```
public class ValidateModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var controller = context.Controller as Controller;
            context.Result = controller.View();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps :)